# tfs force rebase from parent to child branch

Tags: version-control, tfs, merge, rebase, tfvc

I have looked all over for a way to force a rebase when merging in TFS.  I am looking for a way to force developers to get latest of the parent branch and merge it down into their own branch before merging back up to the parent.  Most results now are coming back with GIT articles but we are using TFVC.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-tge-box way to 'force' developers to do this.

Professional developers should always make sure they have an up to date workspace and have completed a build and run unit tests before checkin in. This is a discipline issue.

You could create a checkin policy that checks for this. But that would be over kill.
..